# How to change {value} inside string

Tags: javascript

I have defined a template like this:

```
let template =
'<table border="{border}">' +
'  <tr><td>{first}</td><td>{last}</td></tr>' +
'</table>';
```

And now I wonder how I can change the values inside `{ param }`
so `f.e` for data

```
let data= {
first: "Jack",
last:  "Sparrow"
};
```

the output would be:

```
   <table border="{border}">
<tr><td>Jack</td><td>Sparrow</td></tr>
</table>
```

{border} is not changed, because the new value was not given in data.

Comment: Note that this is dangerous: a user can add additional tags (XSS)

Answer (score 1):

Whats the fallow code do:

1. Create a array of the keys in object
2. The foreach will access key by key
3. Creating a regex to find the where the value from object will be used on string
4. Apply the regex in the string and update the value of `template` variable to the value with replaced attributes
5. Write the `template` on document.

```js
let template =
  '<table border="{border}">' +
  '  <tr><td>{first}</td><td>{last}</td></tr>' +
  '</table>';

let data= {
  first: "Jack",
  last:  "Sparrow"
};

// Replacing on string according the attributes in the object
Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`{${key}}`,'gm')
  template = template.replaceAll(regex, data[key])
})
// Showing the result on document
document.write(template);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let template =
'<table border="{border}">' +
'  <tr><td>{first}</td><td>{last}</td></tr>' +
'</table>';

let data = {
  first: "Jack",
  last: "Sparrow" 
}

template = template.replace(/{first}/g, data.first).replace(/{last}/g, data.last);

console.log(template);
```

Try it by replacing the values inside the string with something like
`template.replace(/{first}/g, data.first);`.
This code should replace every "{first}" substring in the template string.

Answer (score 0):

Use .replace method

```js
let template =
'<table border="{border}">' +
'  <tr><td>{first}</td><td>{last}</td></tr>' +
'</table>';

let data= {
first: "Jack",
last:  "Sparrow"
};

let newTemplate = template.replace("{first}", data.first).replace("{last}", data.last);


console.log(newTemplate)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a perfect use case for [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
let data= {
  first: "Jack",
  last:  "Sparrow"
};

let template = `<table border="{border}">
  <tr><td>${data.first}</td><td>${data.last}</td></tr>
</table>`;


console.log(template);
```

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically replace via the data object (as you specified), you can do something like this:

```js
let template =
'<table border="{border}">' +
'  <tr><td>{first}</td><td>{last}</td></tr>' +
'</table>';

let data= {
first: "Jack",
last:  "Sparrow"
};

for (let item in data) {
  template = template.replace(new RegExp(`{${item}}`, 'g'), data[item]);
}

console.log(template);
```